# XML file parsing Python

Tags: element

I am having trouble collecting 2 more pieces of data to convert from XML to CSV using Python

They are the description tag and the generatedOn tag.

For the description tag I tried `item.find('description').text` but it did not work.

For the generatedOn tag I would like it concatenate the items inside like this:

[image]

Please see the sample XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<omGroups xmlns="urn:nortel:namespaces:mcp:oms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:nortel:namespaces:mcp:oms OMSchema.xsd" >

        <group>
                <name>RecordingSystem</name>
                <row>
                        <package>com.nortelnetworks.mcp.ne.base.recsystem.fw.system</package>
                        <class>RecSysFileOMRow</class>
                        <usage name="closedFileCount" hasThresholds="true">
                                <measures>
                                        closed file count
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        This register counts the number
                                        of closed files in the spool directory of a
                                        particular stream and a particular system.
                                        Files in the spool directory store the raw
                                        OAM records where they are sent to the
                                        Element Manager for formatting.
                                </description>
                                <notes>
                                        Minor and major alarms
                                        when the value of closedFileCount
                                        exceeds certain thresholds. Configure
                                        the threshold values for minor and major
                                        alarms for this OM through engineering
                                        parameters for minorBackLogCount and
                                        majorBackLogCount, respectively. These
                                        engineering parameters are grouped under
                                        the parameter group of Log, OM, and
                                        Accounting for the logs’ corresponding
                                        system.
                                </notes>
                        </usage>
                        <usage name="processedFileCount" hasThresholds="true">
                                <measures>
                                        Processed file count
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        The register counts the number
                                        of processed files in the spool directory of
                                        a particular stream and a particular system.
                                        Files in the spool directory store the raw
                                        OAM records and then send the records to
                                        the Element Manager for formatting.
                                </description>
                        </usage>
                </row>
                <documentation>
                        <description>
                                Rows of this OM group provide a count of the number of files contained
                                within the directory (which is the OM row key value).
                        </description>
                        <rowKey>
                                The full name of the directory containing the files counted by this row.
                        </rowKey>
                </documentation>
                <generatedOn>
                        <all/>
                </generatedOn>
        </group>
        <group traffic="true">
                <name>Ports</name>
                <row>
                        <package>com.nortelnetworks.ims.cap.mediaportal.host</package>
                        <class>PortsOMRow</class>
                        <usage name="rtpMpPortUsage">
                                <measures>
                                        BCP port usage
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        Meter showing number of ports in use.
                                </description>
                        </usage>
                        <lwGauge name="connMapEntriesLWM">
                                <measures>
                                        Lowest simultaneous port usage
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        Lowest number of
                                        simultaneous ports detected to be in
                                        use during the collection interval
                                </description>
                        </lwGauge>
                        <hwGauge name="connMapEntriesHWM">
                                <measures>
                                        Highest simultaneous port usage
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        Highest number of
                                        simultaneous ports detected to be in
                                        use during the collection interval.
                                </description>
                        </hwGauge>
                        <waterMark name="connMapEntries">
                                <measures>
                                        Connections map entries
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        Meter showing the number of connections in the host
                                        CPU connection map.
                                </description>
                                <bwg lwref="connMapEntriesLWM" hwref="connMapEntriesHWM"/>
                        </waterMark>
                        <counter name="portUsageSampleCnt">
                                <measures>
                                    Usage sample count
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                    The number of 100-second samples taken during the
                                    collection interval contributing to the average report.
                                </description>
                        </counter>
                        <counter name="sampledRtpMpPortUsage">
                                <measures>
                                    In-use ports usage
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                    Provides the sum of the in-use ports every 100 seconds.
                                </description>
                        </counter>
                        <precollector>
                                <package>com.nortelnetworks.ims.cap.mediaportal.host</package>
                                <class>PortsOMCenturyPrecollector</class>
                                <collector>centurySecond</collector>
                        </precollector>
                </row>
                <documentation>
                        <description>
                        </description>
                        <rowKey>
                        </rowKey>
                </documentation>
                <generatedOn>
                        <list>
                            <ne>sessmgr</ne>
                            <ne>rtpportal</ne>
                        </list>
                </generatedOn>
        </group>
       
</omGroups>
```

Code

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, 'html.parser')

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(['General name:SpecificName', 'RegisterType', 'Measures'])
    for item in soup.select('row [name]'):
        writer.writerow([item.find_previous('name').text + ':' + item['name'], item.name, item.find('measures').get_text(strip=True)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
import csv
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, 'html.parser')

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(['General name:SpecificName', 'RegisterType', 'Measures', 'Description', 'generatedOn'])
    for item in soup.select('row [name]'):
        desc = item.find('description').get_text(strip=True) 
        desc = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', desc)
        generatedOn = ','.join(ne.get_text(strip=True) for ne in item.find_parent('group').select('ne'))
        writer.writerow([item.find_previous('name').text + ':' + item['name'], item.name, item.find('measures').get_text(strip=True), desc, generatedOn])
```

Generates `data.csv`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not really understand how re.sub works though

Comment: @marcorivera8 The `re.sub('\s{2,}',...)` just replaces multiple whitespaces with single whitespace. You can skip this command if you don't need it.